# Snowflake to SSIS

Tags: ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ssis-2012

I am getting this error "indicator pointer is required by the driver to indicate null output data" while I am importing data from Snowflake to SQL server using SSIS. I have created an ODBC driver connection in order to access it. I am able to do it for some of the views but unfortunately for 1 of the view it is throwing me this error :

> [SnowFlake Query for Unwinding [398]] Error: SQLSTATE: 22002,
> Message: [Snowflake][ODBC] (10450) Indicator pointer is required by
> the driver to indicate NULL output data, but is not provided.:
> [SnowFlake Query for Unwinding [398]] Error: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_INDUCED TRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "SnowFlake Query for
> Unwinding. Outputs [ODBC Source Output]" failed because error code
> 0xC020F450 occurred, and the error row disposition on "SnowFlake
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The
> PrimeOutput method on SnowFlake Query for Unwinding returned error
> code 0xC0209029. The component returned a failure code when the
> pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of

Comment: Hi , please check in the Target table in Snowflake, is the column NOT null and you are getting Null valuesfrom SQL server view.

Comment: The error message you're seeing typically occurs when you're trying to retrieve a NULL value from the database without providing a means for the ODBC driver to identify that the data is, in fact, NULL.

Comment: It might be necessary to iteratively work out what column(s) or rows are causing the issue, then apply some special SQL to clean it up on the way through. For example you should select a limited set of columns and iterate until you work out what column is causing the issue. Then you might just be able to use `IFNULL` in your snowflake query to hide it.